# How to reset state of metrics after prometheus scrapes it?

Tags: java, spark-streaming, prometheus

I am new to Prometheus and currently integrating spark streaming metrics to prometheus. I am collecting different metrics on Batch Completed event in spark streaming and want to store those metrics to prometheus. Note that on every batch completed event i have a metric which need to be **scraped** to prometheus. I know that prometheus follows pull model. Also i see it has push exporters which just pushes the latest metrics values, but in my case since its based on completed event so it can be list of metrics so i can't follow that approach. How should i design such system?

I am thinking of storing my metrics in a buffer and exposing a rest call (where i will reset my metrics as prometheus already consumed it) which prometheus server will listen. Is it the correct way? or we can do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prometheus Pushgateway [https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway] can help you with this, you can create clients which will push the metrics of the job once completed. You can find different implementations at the below link

https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/